# How to add custom code snippet with argument in prefix [VS CODE]

Tags: visual-studio-code, code-snippets, vscode-snippets

For example, i am using React, and i tired to write every time full line:
`const [state, setState] = React.useState("start value")`
I wanna shortcut this to `usestate state` where **usestate** is the command and **state** is parameter.
More examples:
`usestate isLoading` -> `const [isLoading, setIsLoading] = React.useState($0)`
How to rich it?

Comment: use extension Hypersnips

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to be able to type something like `usestate isLoading` and have it automatically expand to your desired output, then [HyperSnips](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=draivin.hsnips) is a good way to go.  But it will take more of a set-up then other ways to accomplish what you want.

If using HyperSnips, put this into your `javascriptreact.json` file that it will help you create:

```
snippet `(usestate)\s+([^ ]+) ` "expand to jsx setState" A
``
let state = m[2];
rv=`const [${m[2]}, set${m[2][0].toUpperCase()}${m[2].substring(1)}] = React.useState($0)`
``
endsnippet
```

[image: react setstate with hypersnips demo]

Note the trigger `(usestate)\s+([^ ]+)`  has a space at the end!  That is necessary since the regex is looking for non-space characters for the `state` and it will know that by the first space character.

[Right now, the tabstop `$0` or `$1` aren't working for me...]

---

There are a number of other ways to approach this.  The simplest is probably to just make a snippet like the following (in one of your snippets files):

```
"React setState": {
  "prefix": "usestate",
  "body": [
    // "const [${TM_SELECTED_TEXT/^.*\\s+(.)(.*)$/$1$2, set${1:/upcase}$2/}] = React.useState($0)"
    "const [$1, ${1/(.)(.*)/set${1:/upcase}$2/}] = React.useState($0)"
  ]
}
```

[image: react setState demo]

Here you type the prefix `usestate`, choose that snippet from the suggestions and then type `isLoading`, <kbd>Tab</kbd> and then snippet completes.

It isn't the workflow you asked for but it is simpler than getting something like HyperSnips up and running.

---

Another approach if you really want to type `usestate isLoading` and then trigger completion is to use a macro extension like [multi-command](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ryuta46.multi-command).  You need that to select what you have typed so that it gets replaced when the snippet is inserted.  This would be a keybinding - not a snippet, although it inserts a snippet.  Put this into your `keybindings.json`:

```
{
  "key": "alt+i",      // whatever keybinding you want
  "command": "extension.multiCommand.execute",
  "args": {
    "sequence": [
      "cursorHomeSelect",
      {
        "command": "editor.action.insertSnippet",
        "args": {
          "snippet": "const [${TM_SELECTED_TEXT/^.*\\s+(.)(.*)$/$1$2, set${1:/upcase}$2/}] = React.useState($0)"
        }
      }
    ]
  },
}
```

[image: React setstate keybinding demo]